# Figuring out the stride of a C++ class in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a class from which I'm trying to draw an asteroid(octagon).  The asteroid class has two members.  A `vertex` specifying its location and `vertices` specifying the points in the octagon.  My question is how do I figure out the stride and the offset (for glVertexAttribPointer and glBufferData) of an object of this class in order to draw it?

```
class asteroid
{
  std::pair <float, float> vertex;  
  std::vector<std::pair <float, float>> vertices;
}
```

Then I have a `vector<asteroid> asteroids;` to store all my asteroids.

Comment: What's wrong with `sizeof`?

Comment: This gives only the stride, but not the offset.

Comment: If the asteroid always has 8 points, I would just use an array instead of a dynamically allocated vector.

Comment: Another comment: You assume here, that the elements of a vector a stored  inside the class, which is not the fact. Only the vector object is stored in the class, but elements can be stored anywhere in dynamic memory. Summary: uploading asteroids to gpu will not upload the content of vertices.

Comment: So then how do I load the vertices data stored in dynamic memory?

Comment: You have to upload the vertices of each asteroid to the buffer with glBufferSubdata. This allows you to concatenate the different memory blocks in one buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The stride of the vertices is `sizeof(vertices[0])` and the offset to upload to glBufferData is `reinterpret_cast<void*>(&vertices[0])` The offset for glVertexAttribPointer is `reinterpret_cast<void*>(&vertices[0].first) - reinterpret_cast<void*>(&vertices[0])`

However keeping the vertices like that is not a good idea, just create a single (shared) VBO for all asteroids and do away with the vector.

Then you can use [instancing](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing) so the positions of the asteroid will be in a separate VBO and attribute with `glVertexAttribDivisor` set. In the vertex shader you then have a attribute `vertex` and attribute `position`. The `vertex` attribute is the vertices VBO and the `position` is the position field of the asteroids.

Comment: I'm kind of lost as to how to set up a VBO. In fact, I'm not quite sure what it does. From the Red Book all I know is that I must `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, my_buffer)` in order to get anything to draw but have no clue what my_buffer does or is.

Answer (score 1):

Stride :

The difference between the beginning of one attribute to it's next occurrence in the same model .

That being said, the stride of your binded attribute is sizeof(vertex), where vertex contains attributes like position of 3 floats, color of 3 floats etc. Each attribute (position, color) needs to know it's stride.

The offset is the place within the vertex where the attribute starts.

Now for some code sample

```
  struct vertex
  {
        float position[3];
        float color[3];
        float uv[2]; 
  }
```

When biding attributes,

```
 position : offset 0 , stride sizeof(vertex)
 color : offset 3* sizeof(float) (because of position) , stride sizeof(vertex)
 uv : offset 6 * sizeof(float) (position + color before) , stride sizeof(vertex)
```

What you defined in your structure doesn't make much sense.

A vertex isn't composed of two floats. What you have there is POSITION in 2D of the object. That information should be used to create the World Matrix.

Next you have vertices, who should be an array of VERTEX (as I defined in the above sample).

What you considered inside your code is that it's an array of floats representing your vertices with 2d location as x and y.

An equivalent of your code would be to write the Vertex structure as being

```
 struct Vertex {
      float Position[2];
 }
```

Then, in this case you would have for the attribute Position the offset 0 and the stride sizeof(Vertex) which is 2 * sizeof(float);